# Activating toolbar in ArcPad?

Tags: arcpad, toolbar

I would like a user to select from a form a particular thing to measure, and for the form to close and show the `Draw` toolbar as the toolbar currently focused. My current code is (when a button is clicked):

```js
function measureFeature(layer_name) {
    /* Activates the layer for editing and closes the form */

    closeForm(); // function defined elsewhere to close form
    Application.Map.Layers(layer_name).Editable = true;
    // Focus 'Draw' toolbar here
}
```

All I am missing is something along the lines of:

```js
Application.Toolbars.Item('Draw').Focus();
```

or

```js
Application.focusedToolbar = 'Draw';
```

Does this even exist, maybe under a different method or object?

Also asked here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/55469, but with no answer in 2 years

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are mixing concepts here. To my knowledge tool bars don't "activate" as you are asking for. You can set the *visibility* of a toolbar so they appear or get hidden but they are always "active".

If you have a *Button* that you want "active" then you use the method *SetFocus*.

Comment: Ok, the devil being in the detail of easily confused UI terms: what I want to happen is the Draw toolbar be set to the toolbar in focus (not 'Visible' = true/false - this just sets whether it is completely hidden). In this case, my custom toolbar would currently be the one in focus, because that's how I get to my custom form. When I close the form I want the Draw toolbar to be in focus so the user can instantly choose a capture method, without the script selecting one for them.